# Firebase Storage - Upload Blob Url

Tags: firebase, blob, firebase-storage

I have a blob url such as :

```
blob:http://localhost:4200/06a6baa9-b7ff-4171-9dc2-a1caed35e099
```

and when passing into

```
  this.storage.ref('users/' + uid + '/mainPhoto').put(imageURL))
```

I am receiving this error:

> Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to upload the blob from the blob url,
and than upload it to firebase storage

**Upload Function**:

```
uploadToStorage = (imageURL) = >{

     getFileBlob(imageURL, blob =>{
        firebase.storage().ref().put(blob).then(function(snapshot) {
           console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
        })
    })
}
```

**getBlob Function**:

```
var getFileBlob = function (url, cb) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", url);
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
        cb(xhr.response);
      });
      xhr.send();
    };
```

Comment: this is the best solution when using expo.. for some reason now fetch does not work..

Comment: Where does the getFileBlob come from?

Answer (score 4):

Referring to dan's solution, it works for me after 2 amendments for **Upload Function**:-

1. there should be a 'var' in front of "uploadToStorage = (imageURL)..."
2. there should not have spacing for '=>'

**Upload Function**

```
var uploadToStorage = (imageURL) => {

     getFileBlob(imageURL, blob =>{
        firebase.storage().ref().put(blob).then(function(snapshot) {
           console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
        })
    })
}
```